# cannot resolve symbol createTempFile

Tags: java, android, file

I have absolutely no clue why this is creating an error. Can someone please explain.

```
import java.io.File;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.View;

public final class Util
{
static Bitmap image;

public static File getOutputMediaFile(byte[] data)
{

    image= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);


    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "FrontFlash");



    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists())
    {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) return null;
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile=null;

    //mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

       mediaFile = new File.createTempFile("dsadsa", ".jpg");

    return mediaFile;
}
```

Comment: `createTempFile` is *static* method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that it the compiler cannot resolve `createTempFile` to a type so it cannot instantiate [`File#createTempFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) as it is a `static` method.

Remove the `new` keyword:

```
mediaFile = File.createTempFile("dsadsa", ".jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
mediaFile = File.createTempFile("dsadsa", ".jpg");
```